# How to not render/display a variable returned in flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a string variable that is coming from an HTML form and I want to use it as a parameter for other functions. However, flask renders the variable instead of rendering other stuff. The variable in question in my case is sub

```
@server.route('/')
def main():  
    return render_template("main.html")          #HTML input form is here 

@server.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
def index_post(): 
    sub = request.form['search_sub']             #sub is user input    
    return sub                                   # Don't want render. Just normal return   

@server.route('/index') #This page should load after user enters on form
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@server.route('/index/result', methods=['POST']) # This is where sub will be needed
@cache_flask.cached(timeout=240) 
def result():
    sub = index_post()                          # declaring sub here?
    main_info = redditnlp.version125_flask(sub) # sub is a parameter here
    return render_template("result.html", main_info=main_info)
```

If it helps, here are my HTML files for main.html and index.html

```
main.html

<form action="/index", method = "POST">
    <input id ="input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Insert subreddit" name="search_sub">
</form>


index.html

<form action="/index/result" method="POST">
    <button id="result_button" class="button"><span>See sentiment results</span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is hard to understand. Why can't you just get `request.form['search_sub ']` in the `result()` function? And what do you mean by "rendering the variable"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry if it's unclear. When I do `sub = request.form['search_sub'] ` in `result()` I get result `400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'search_sub' ` I figured if I just returned the user's input as a string variable then I can avoid this error. What I mean by render is that flask produces a web page with the value of the user input.

Comment: I still don't understand. What does "return the user's input as a string variable" mean? If you're getting that error, it's because there is no such form data in the request, so I can't see how calling another function within that same request would help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using [`Flask-Caching`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Caching/) or [`Flask-Cache`](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cache/).

First of all, it appears that you are trying to cache the value of the `search_sub` form field for future requests by caching the `result()` view function. You are, however, caching the wrong view function. You should cache `index_post()` because that is the view that produces the value that you want to retain between requests.

Secondly, that's not going to work. Direct calls to the cached view will bypass the cache because the key name defaults to the route path. You can override this by supplying your own key in the `key_prefix` argument:

```
@server.route('/index', methods=['POST'])
@server.cache.cached(timeout=240, key_prefix='index_post')
def index_post():
    sub = request.form['search_sub']
    return sub
```

This sets the cache key to `index_post`. Now calling the function directly, or as a view, will work.

---

This seems a very convoluted way of going about it. Perhaps you should look at Flask's inbuilt [`sessions`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions).

Comment: Sorry I don't think my initial question made sense. The thing is, the `main()` function is (if you can call it) like the google home page. The user enters in this case, the subreddit they want to look up and the `index()` function would then give them options in the form of buttons for the functions they want to call, `result()` is one of them. pt1

Comment: ...What I'm trying to do is for my input/`search_sub` to be loaded to the `result()` function because `redditnlp.version125_flask(sub)` a function from another Python file requires `search_sub` or `sub` as a parameter. **The main issue I'm having is getting the user's input from `main()`  and inserting it as the parameter `sub` for the python function `redditnlp.version125_flask(sub)` under `result()`.** The reason I had cache for `result()` was because this function takes a while to load the data when you first call it because it's garbing data from Reddit. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Use flask [sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions). Add `sub` to the session in `index_post()`. Then you can access it in other views such as `result()` in subsequent requests.